# time depended workflow is made inactive, is that it will still send the email

Tags: email, workflow, time

I have implemented the time depended workflow to send email after 10 days. Now 4 days are left to trigger the work flow to send the mail. But new i dont have a need to send the email hence  i have deactive the rule.
my question is still the emaill will be sent on 10th day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any alerts which were scheduled before the rule was deactivated will still be sent, as long as the criteria for the workflow rule is still met at the scheduled time.

In case if you do not want to send the email, then follow these steps :-

From setup--> in the Quick find --> enter Time-based Workflow -->In the search criteria, please put Object equals 'your related object name' and search to see what Time Based workflows are queued up. You will see everything that is pending based on the criteria.

If there are any workflows pending, you can sort based on the rule name and then delete all pending actions.